# how to pass array as an answer to Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I`m trying to add array answers to my simple model, but I can not understand how to do that.
I have input shape of 2d array, one example [[0, 0, 1][1, 0, 0]] and the answer for this example is [0, 1] 
It is like Rock, Paper, Scissors between 2 players and answer is who won, so I have all possible training data which is 9 examples.

My code so far:

I have created a class BooleanNN:

```
class BooleanNN:
    def __init__(self, name, inputs, answers, load=False, twolayers=False):
        self.name = name
        if load:  
            self.model = keras.models.load_model(f'{name}.h5')
        else:
            self.model = keras.models.Sequential()
            self.model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[2,3], name='input'))
            if twolayers: 
              # for xor 
              self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='hidden'))
            self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output'))
            self.model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss='mean_squared_error')
            for _ in range(10):
              self.model.fit(inputs, answers, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
              print(self.model.evaluate(inputs, answers, verbose=0))
            self.model.save(f'{name}.h5')

        self.evaluate(inputs, answers)
        print(self.model.summary())
        print(self.model.get_weights())

    def evaluate(self, inputs, answers):
        print(f'Network "{self.name}"\n-----------------------')
        results = self.model.predict(inputs)
        for input, result, correct in zip(inputs, results, answers):
            print(f'{input} : \n got {result} \n necessary {correct}')

    def train_some_more(self, inputs, answers):
      for _ in range(5):
        self.model.fit(inputs, answers, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
        print(self.model.evaluate(inputs, answers, verbose=0))
      self.evaluate(inputs, answers)}
```

And then when I try to call class BooleanNN I need to pass the answers but I am really struggling with that. I did not add all data as I am trying to experiment with lot of different ways how to pass it and I would not have to change everything all the time.

This is how far I got:

```
inputs = [([0., 0.,1.], [1., 0.,0.])]
answers = [0.,1.]
network = BooleanNN('net1', inputs, answers)
```

Which is followed with error

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 2
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input data format is not quite right. Here's a way you can do:

```
# generate 10 samples of data
inputs = np.random.random((10,2,3)) 
answers = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 2, 1)) 
network = BooleanNN('net1', inputs, answers)
```

Make sure the shape of input data is same as defined in the network architecture.